# ORACLE PL/SQL How to create ParentID in Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a procedure that loads data from a table, and has a "child" and "parent" relationship (DEPARTMENT_CODE and PARENT_DEPARTMENT_CODE). So I also have two columns with the IDs of those columns, the column "ID_DEPARTMENT" is auto increment from Oracle create table, but the "PARENTID_DEPARTMENT" needs to have the "ID_DEPARTMENT" filled in according to the two columns mentioned above.
For fields that do not have parents, you should leave this blank.

That is, how do you do this in an "Insert into" procedure in Oracle?

**What I have:**

[image]

**What I need:**

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: you would not use an `INSERT` to fix the data. You would need an `UPDATE` . Can you please add an example of what you have tried, provide an example of the input and the desired output.

Comment: I updated the question, with what I have and what I need. I didn't tried anything yet, because I don't know what and how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed your table is named YourTable

```
UPDATE YourTable t1 
SET t1.PARENTID_DEPARTMENT = (SELECT t2.ID_DEPARTMENT
                              FROM YourTable t2 
                              WHERE t1.PARENT_DEPARTMENT_CODE = t2.DEPARTMENT_CODE)
WHERE t1.PARENT_DEPARTMENT_CODE <> ''
AND EXISTS (SELECT t2.ID_DEPARTMENT
            FROM YourTable t2 
            WHERE t1.PARENT_DEPARTMENT_CODE = t2.DEPARTMENT_CODE)
```

Comment: It didn't work, it kept all column (PARENTID_DEPARTMENT) blank yet, but it didn't show any error.

Comment: If I run only this, it works (without the WHERE clause): `UPDATE YourTable t1 
SET t1.PARENTID_DEPARTMENT = (SELECT t2.ID_DEPARTMENT
                              FROM YourTable t2 
                              WHERE t1.PARENT_DEPARTMENT_CODE = t2.DEPARTMENT_CODE)`

Comment: From the screenshots it was not clear if you had `NULL` or blank spaces. I now assume they were nulls and hence no need for the `WHERE` clause

Comment: I just changed the clause `WHERE t1.PARENT_DEPARTMENT_CODE <> ''` to `WHERE t1.PARENT_DEPARTMENT_CODE IS NOT NULL` and it worked like a charm! Really thanks for your time and effort!